# How to store optionals

Tags: swift, realm

As Realm doesn't support optionals, which are not `Object` subclasses, I'm trying to wrap a string into `StringObject`:

```
final class StringObject: Object {
    dynamic var value: String = ""

    convenience init?(_ value: String?) {
        self.init()

        if let value = value {
            self.value = value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
final class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: StringObject? // can be optional
}
```

But this solution has a nasty side effect: as `StringOptional` values will be stored in their own table within the database, there will be countless duplicate values every time a `StringObject` is created. I tried making `StringObject`'s `value` a primary key, but upon `Person` object's creation I receive an error:

> Can't set primary key property 'lastName' to existing value 'Doe'

Which means that internally Realm does not upsert relationships.

Is there a better way to store optionals?

Answer (score 2):

We actually released a beta of Realm that had support for optional strings and data properties, and it will hopefully be released more widely soon! In the meantime, you can try out the beta at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/628#issuecomment-106952727.

Comment: I saw it and I'm really looking forward for full optional support, but my questions used `String` as an example coincidentally and it may as well be a type, whose optionals are not yet supported.

So is there any way to work around this limitation with the latest stable release? `Object` wrapper seemed like a good idea, but a table full of `StringObject` duplicates feels quite wrong. Like I mentioned in the question, primary key doesn't really help as relationships are not upserted.

Thanks, @segiddins!

Comment: You can manually do upsets for the relationship, and that's about all that comes to mind.